# IL (MSIL) And Inside Of dll

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I researched about MSIL (IL) and CLR and the other thing like processing path from source code through the OS [image: like this]

We can see Intermediate Language in the third step. I want to know are `.dll` files written exactly with Intermediate Language?

[image]

this is a `.dll` file insider code example, is this code called Intermediate Language?

I searched in the internet for MSIL code example and I saw this image below

[image]

these are different and because it i doubted.

thanks

Comment: "yes, your dlls are (usually) packed with lots of IL, not machine code" - that do? although the fragment shown is just some xml manifest data

Comment: .NET DLLs contain IL, but it's packaged as a Windows PE file, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/file-format). When you look at the bytes of the DLL you'll see the PE Headers, some other stuff, and then the actual IL. The thing you've posted is just a UTF-8-encoded XML file. That particular one looks like a [ClickOnce application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-application-manifest?view=vs-2019)

Comment: The answer is yes. Next question ?

Comment: Technically it's now called `CIL` (Common Intermediate Language) rather than `IL`. /pedantmode

Comment: @TheGeneral
No Thank you But I saw different MSIL Code Examples in the internet and because it I doubted.

Comment: Show what you saw (in your question) so we can understand where you are and your reasoning/context

Comment: It will be a lot interesting if you do parse an executable/assembly using a library like [PEFile](https://github.com/secana/PeNet) which shows how a PE32 envolope actually looks like and how .NET metadata are embedded. Then compare to a native Windows library (written in C/C++) to see the differences.

Comment: `I want to know are .dll files written exactly with Intermediate Language?` the Microsoft dot net compilers compile to MSIL. Unity for instance takes C# code and AOT compiles it into ASM or Machine Code. there are compilers that compile .net into all sorts of things however none of them can be classed as a .net assembly.... DLL is just and extension. however a dll can be .net or a PE file, or anything really, who khnows?

Comment: The final image you posted shows the output of ildasm. This has read the IL from a file (exe or dll), and formatted it in a human-readable way. The IL is actually stored in a binary format, the details of which are in ECMA-335. You almost certainly don't need to learn how to read the binary encoding of IL: it has complex parts, and there are plenty of tools to turn it into a human-readable form (like the one in you image)

Comment: @canton7
So you mean final picture is a human-readable source code?  the first step in first picture?

Comment: @Amin: That's correct. You could write code like that (if you were a masochist) and then turn it into compiled IL using the ILASM tool (part of the .NET SDK).

Comment: @Amin Depends on what you mean by "Source Code". It's not C# or VB source code. It's a human-readable representation of what C#/VB is compiled into

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually test this yourself.
Create a new Library project, and a single function:

```
public class Class1 {
    public static int Add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Compile into a DLL, and open the DLL in [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy). Navigate to your `Add()` function, and change the dropdown from `C#` to `IL`. You'll see something like this:

```
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldarg.1
    IL_0003: add
    IL_0004: stloc.0
```

These are the human-readable representation of your IL. In ILSpy you can click on each of the instructions (e.g. `ldarg.0`) to see what they do, and their hexadecimal instruction code. Wikipedia has a [full list of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions).

So our `Add()` function in CIL would be the following:

| opcode | instruction | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x02 | ldarg.0 | Load argument 0 onto the stack. |
| 0x03 | ldarg.1 | Load argument 1 onto the stack. |
| 0x58 | add | Add two values, returning a new value. |
| 0x0A | stloc.0 | Pop a value from stack into local variable 0. |

Notice the hexadecimal opcodes there. Now open up the DLL in a hex editor. If you look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/contents), you'll notice that the top parts are not actual code.

If your hex editor has a search, go look for the hex sequence of our opcodes, and you'll see that in the middle of your file, you would find:

```
02 03 58 0a
```

Which is what your IL would look like inside a DLL!